# Ubuntu Nvidia Driver 310.14Beta Stretch OpenGL Feature

Tags: nvidia, graphics, games, ubuntu-netbook, opengl

I have a HP Mini 311 running an outdated version of the Nvidia drivers (The recomended from the additional drivers option), alongside my Ubuntu 12.04.

Now the problem I am running into is the feature "Stretch OpenGL" is missing from new releases. I play many old games like StarCraft 1, Diablo 1 and 2, etc. and without the stretch feature on these games they take up 1/10 of my screen making playing extremely horrible on my display (1366x768). I will provide more specs below, but I was wondering if anyone using the new 310.14beta driver has seen the option or know how to enable Stretched OpenGL to fit the screen?

System Specs:

```
HP Mini 311
3 GB ram
Nvidia Ion 1.66 GHZ
512 MB Video Card
320 GB HDD
1366X768 HD Display
Ubuntu 12.04 (tested 12.10 and ran too choppy on my laptop)
```

Comment: so it seems that I am not the only one who is running into this issue.  Perhaps its because it is marked as a "Beta" driver that some of those features are disabled...